# Having very specific search issue when using ajax call in conjunction with PHP & MySql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Here it is in a nutshell:

JS FILE AJAX CALL:

```
var searchString = 'value';

$.ajax({ 
    type:'POST', 
    url:'myUrl.php', 
    data:{ 
        'searchString': searchString 
    }, 
    async:false, 
    dataType:'json', 
    success: function(data){ 
        // do stuff 
    }, 
    error: function(data){ 
        console.log(data); 
    } 
});
```

PHP FILE:

```
$searchString = $_POST['searchString'];
```

mysql query:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE searchField LIKE '%" . $searchString . "%'";
```

All of the above works perfectly with one exception: if the searchString variable value is 'grb' it does not produce an error, but also produces no results (and there are 60+ "matching records" that should be found on a 'grb' search).

I can do the exact same query (as shown in `$q` above) successfully with 'grb' from within phpMyAdmin using the 'Search' option on the 'searchField' selecting the 'LIKE %...%' operator OR clicking on 'SQL' and using:

```
SELECT * FROM `myTable` WHERE `searchField` LIKE '%grb%'
```

The problem seems to only exist when 'grb' is sent via the ajax call. Same ajax call with anything other than 'grb' WORKS properly.

NOTE: THE `searchString` variable is actually set from a "input" text on a form that is set so that only lower case letters and numbers can be entered.

Comment: Do you still have the problem if you fix your code to use parameters instead of concatenating `$searchString`? That's a good idea anyway, as you're currently wide open to SQL injection.

Comment: Can you show what `console.log(data);` produces after the ajax call?

Comment: First of all, you are not sanitizing the `$_POST` variable before sending it to mysql. That is a large open door to anyone who wants to mess with your DB. Second, please show us what console.log(data) returns on the `success` function with `rgb`

Comment: there is a return variable from the php file "searchResults" (i.e. data.searchResults) that is an array object. You can see the "array object" with console.log (null if search produced no matching records) when db records match the search. In the case of 'grb' and ONLY 'grb' data.searchResults returns 'undefined' with console.log. In all other cases, console.log(data.searchResults) returns either the object when records are found or null if none are.

Comment: And Cornel: your inquired about console.log on 'rgb' - the issue is 'grb' - 'rgb' returns null as it should as no records would match 'rgb'

Comment: Just realized I typed out the "data" portion of the ajax call incorrectly it should read: data: {  postVars: {  'searchString':searchString } }. The php file then "posts" postVars and $searchString = $postVars->searchString

Comment: No one has any idea why 'grb' and only 'grb' won't work? I've tried several approaches concerning the variable as far as how it is sent/received by the ajax call/php file. Every search produces what it should with the exception of 'grb' which is returning undefined for the 'searchResults' variable.